# Scipy Median Filter Which Ignores Zero-Valued Datapoints?

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, scipy.ndimage

I have been using the `median_filter` function from `scipy.ndimage`. I would like to use this in a way that discards any data that isn't positively valued.

That is, suppose one iteration of the filter acts over:

```
[40, 50, 0, 90]
```

If I simply run the median filter over this, I will get **45**. I desire a function which ignores the zero, such that the median is **50**.

Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score -1):

In excel we do this by providing an if statement [then is implied.]

=IF(SUM(F38,F43,F47)>60,60,IF(SUM(F38,F43,F47)<34,34,(SUM(F38,F43,F47))))
This would make any answer over 60 equal to 60.
=IF(E19*A19=0,"", E19*A19) ignores 0.
=IF(E19*A19<=0,"", E19*A19) returns nothing for 0 or any negative number. I hope this leads you in the right direction. It will depend on your platform but you are looking for eliminating all non positive inputs. something to the effect of
input [n]
If input [n] <= 0 zero, return null.
next input.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).